# Activating an animation on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm using http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html in a project and cannot seem to get the animation to activate when scrolled to. The animation starts as soon as I load that page.

http://jsfiddle.net/m2phK/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#object').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+200) {
            $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('#object').each( ...` seems strange, you only have one single element with that ID, right ?

Comment: $.each() is designed to work over a collection of objects. Have you tested that part to make sure it's implemented correctly?

Comment: Hummm, I've copied the code directly from the source. I'm wondering if Im overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the script, so it runs the animation as soon as the box enters the viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/yq3Hc/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#object').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+imagePos) {
                $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
            }
        });
});
```

Before I added "imagePos" there was a value (in your case 200). That means you need to scroll the box up until there are 200px between the top of the browser window and the box. Since nothing comes after your box and you cannot sroll it that far up, you need to change that.

I hope this helps.